# bootstrap button groups horizontal to vertical in column grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a group of buttons in the bootstrap grid system. When the window is narrow the buttons look like this:

[image]

But when the window is wide, the buttons look like this:

[image]

How do I make the buttons have the class "btn-group-vertical" when the window is wide, so that it will look like this...

[image]

(note: I can't just set the class to btn-group-vertical all the time, or else when the window is narrow it pushes the side picture bellow the column of buttons and because buttons wont span side-by-side across the top.)

Current Code (removed all PHP fluff):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div  class="btn-group" align="center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button_has_long_name</button>  
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button_short</button>  
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button_another_long</button>  
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button_etc</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <img style="width:900px" id="shown_image" src="./images/empty.jpg">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your code or a minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use some js to make it possible.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/15896/)

**JS**

```
var wideScreen = 640; // for example beyond 640 is considered wide

var toggleBtnGroup = function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  
  if(windowWidth > wideScreen) {
    $('#btn-group-toggle').addClass('btn-group-vertical').removeClass('btn-group');

  } else {
    $('#btn-group-toggle').addClass('btn-group').removeClass('btn-group-vertical');
  }
}

toggleBtnGroup(); // trigger on load

window.addEventListener('resize',toggleBtnGroup); // change on resize
```

Comment: For bootstrap 4, replace #btn-group-toggle to .btn-group-toggle

Answer (score 2):

Try flexbox:

```
@media(min-width: 960px){
 .btn-group {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hwj860o7/3/

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML code add an id for the button group, and then in the CSS code, refer to that id and change the display to inline-grid as I did below:

// HTML code

```
   <div id="multiple-buttons" class="btn-group" role="group">
           <button id="bt1" type="button" class="btn">Button1</button>
           <button id="bt2" type="button" class="btn">Button2</button>
           <button id="bt3" type="button" class="btn">Button3</button>
     </div>
```

// CSS code

```
#multiple-buttons{
          display: inline-grid;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a css media call. Something like this:

```
div.btn-group{
    //css for narrow screen
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
    div.btn-group{
        //css for wide screen
    }
}
```

And have your buttons use the class btn-group everywhere. When the screen has a minimum width of 800px, or whatever number you want to set it at, the widescreen css will take effect.